# Find matrices in text file

Tags: python, matrix

I am python beginner, I'm trying to extract matrices from my data file. This file contains info about some parameters from measurement, e.i. text + numbers. I want to extract the matrices which are placed between words "#UBI:" and "#translation". The file contains hundreds of these matrices. So here is my code I was trying to run - it gave me some results but it seems that there is an infinite loop - it never stops:

```
inF = open("C:/Python27/allgrainmap3.map")

line=inF.readline()

while True:
    inF = open("C:/Python27/allgrainmap3.map")
    outF = open("matrices.txt", "w")
    keepCurrentSet = False
    for line in inF:

        if line.startswith("#translation"):
            keepCurrentSet = False

        if keepCurrentSet:
            outF.write(line)

        if line.startswith("#UBI:"):
            keepCurrentSet = True

    if not line: break

inF.close()
outF.close()
```

the block of the file looks like :

```
translation 4141 14141
bla bla 
bla bla 
UBI: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 # this is the matrix I want
```

translation ... 
In adition - I want only last column of my matrix e.i. vector containing (3 6 9) here.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the input file a two different places in your code which seems like NOT what you want to do.

Also I fail to see the purpose of the `while True:` which is propbably the cause of the infinite loop ...

It seems to me that this would work

```
inF = open("C:/Python27/allgrainmap3.map")
outF = open("matrices.txt", "w")
keepCurrentSet = False
for line in inF:

        if line.startswith("#translation"):
            keepCurrentSet = False

        if keepCurrentSet:
            outF.write(line)

        if line.startswith("#UBI:"):
            keepCurrentSet = True

inF.close()
outF.close()
```

Now if you want to keep only the last column you have to deal with that before writing it to the outfile :

```
 if keepCurrentSet:
   vector = line[9::3]
   outF.write(vector)
```

This will work only with your current matrix  : if the number of column change you would have to compute which elements to keep in the slice.

Edit : If you have numbers instead of single digits in the matrix :

```
line = "UBI: 101 223 33456 40 51 63 75 86 99"
fields = line.split()
vector = fields[3::3]
print(vector)
```

Only works with a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first thing helped me. But the second one - with this vector doesn't work correctly. It doesn't treat the numbers as numbers but as string, I don't know why. So with 9::3 it takes every 3rd digit of the number ... do you think that it's possible that there is a way how to write these numbers to output file as an array for example? It could maybe help to solve this problem.

Comment: edited . you will still have to adapt this for different matrix sizes.

Comment: This didn't work either, dont know why. For me the easiest solution would be just to print last 11 characters of the line (since the numbers have 9 digits like: -1,389348934). So if I print only last 11 characters I have the number and the sign as well. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I just replaced 

 vector = line[9::3]
 outF.write(vector)

by
 
fields = line.split()
vector = fields[3::3]
outF.write(vector)

Comment: could I post somewhere the file with data ? It would be mabe easier for you to check if it works properly...

Comment: and why did you put print(vector) instead of outF.write(vector) ? when I tried it with  outF.write(vector) it gave me: outF.write(vector)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: `outF.write(' '.join(vector))`